Error 140029 in GridDB Using Docker: PutContainer Method Fails with Go Client
I'm setting up GridDB using Docker and integrating it with a Go client using the official repository and documentation. However, I'm encountering an issue with the PutContainer method. Here's a simplified version of my code:
code:
for containerName := range fullDataset {
        fmt.Println("containerName: ", containerName)
        conInfo, err := griddb_go.CreateContainerInfo(map[string]interface{}{
            "name": containerName,
            "column_info_list": [][]interface{}{
                {"timestamp", griddb_go.TYPE_TIMESTAMP},
                {"id", griddb_go.TYPE_SHORT},
                {"data", griddb_go.TYPE_FLOAT},
                {"temperature", griddb_go.TYPE_FLOAT}},
            "type":    griddb_go.CONTAINER_TIME_SERIES,
            "row_key": true})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR CreateContainerInfo")
        }
        defer griddb_go.DeleteContainerInfo(conInfo)

        _, err = gridstore.PutContainer(conInfo)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR PutContainer, ", err)
        }
    }

When I run this code, I get the following error:
containerName:  test_sensor_1
ERROR PutContainer,  Error with number 140029


I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

The error code you shared indicates it's not actually connecting to your cluster: https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v5_5/GridDB_ErrorCodes.html
something that has tripped me up before is that the official docker cluster name is different than the official cluster name used on bare metal. so maybe you simply need to change the cluster name from 'myCluster' to 'dockerGridDB' as indicated here: https://hub.docker.com/r/griddb/griddb
or you can change the docker cluster name to match what your code already has:
GRIDDB_CLUSTER_NAME=myCluster
